# How IDLE prints a character not supported by sys.stdout.encoding (python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

I am trying to print the heart (♥) character in an idle shell on windows (Python 3.7 64-bit). The sys.stdout.encoding is 'cp1255'. As this character cannot be encoded into 'cp1255', a UnicodeEncodeError should be thrown. However, for some reason, printing works. How does it do this?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp1255'
>>> u"\u2665".encode('cp1255')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    u"\u2665".encode('cp1255')
  File "C:\Users\kobip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2665' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>> print (u"\u2665")
♥
```

My motivation in asking the question is that I want to know, before I try to print, whether the console supports some unicode characters. I can do a try and catch every time I print the risky characters, or I can perform an initial attempt of printing these symbols and determine the behavior of the program based on its success, but I prefer a more elegant solution if possible (without the delay of trying an catching errors all the time, and without printing a wierd sentence to stdout). Currently I use:
`sys.stdout.encoding.lower().startswith('utf')` to chekc console support,
but, as shown here, some consoles (including mine) can print characters not supported by sys.stdout.encoding.

Comment: How did you end up in a situation where sys.stdout.encoding is 'cp1255'? Was this the default for you, or is this something you configured manually? If you configured something, how did you do so?

Comment: It was the default for me. When I run python from the windows console the encoding utf-8, but when I run IDLE, the default is cp1255 (Hebrew).

Comment: `print (u"\u2665")` works as expected because used _font_ contains the `♥` glyph.